# deploying Angular 6 Universal to GCP App Engine

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, angular-universal

I'm looking for an example project that's using Angular 6 Universal and is successfully deploying to GCP App Engine. I've searched GitHub but can't find an example--the Universal Starter doesn't include deployment. Also, my old Angular 5 Universal config is not working for this new V6 project.

The current error is coming from nginx: "502 Bad Gateway"
It seems to be the favicon.ico file that's causing the problem--looks like a Node.js issue. I just dealt with this on a pure Node.js project (not Angular) and was able to resolve it, but I can't find the right config in the Angular context.

server.ts

```
app.use(favicon('src/favicon.ico'));
```

angular.json (start of it)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "appname": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/styles.css"
            ], ...
```

dispatch.yaml (because I have multiple services using the same domain)

```
dispatch:
  # Default service serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
  - url: "*/favicon.ico"
    service: default
```

Comment: Looking at the [nodejs docs samples for App Engine](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/search?q=favicon&unscoped_q=favicon) on Github, it looks like a "serve-favicon" package is being used. Are you using something like that? Also, in the interest of removing a layer of complexity, are you able to get this to work without Angular?

Comment: Yes, I am using serve-favicon. I eventually found the issue (see answer). Thx for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not properly starting Node in package.json. This one line in scripts fixed the problem...

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
```